# Which file attribute changes when we copy a file from some other user's account?

Tags: linux

Which file attribute changes when we copy a file from some other user's account, which may be in our own group or in some other group?

Answer (score 2):

What changes depends on how something is copied.

**Always Changes**

Inode - This maps the data to a physical location on disk, obviously to copy something you are creating a new file elsewhere, so the inode will be different.

**Using `cp -p`**

Ownership/Group - The current user will own the file (unless performing as root/sudo, then copy retains original owner). The group will be the user's default group unless they are a member of the currently set group (unless performing as root/sudo, then copy retains original group).

**Using `cp`**

Ownership - Copy will be owned by current user and that users default group

Modify Time - The modify time will be set to when you copied the file

**Doesn't Change**

Permissions - in that the modes for owner/group/everyone would stay the same, but if the owner and group change then the effective permissions are different.

I think that covers everything, but honestly you're best bet is to do a chmod after your cp if you need to ensure certain permissions.

Comment: You forgot to point out that timestamps may also change.  But it's tricky, since for example a filesystem may be mounted with noatime, or an utility used to copy files restores timestamps, etc. (well, you metioned mtime, but not atime and ctime timestamps)